# DAX previous year date calculation not showing correctly in Power BI measure

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a measure that sums expense amount for the current filtered year.  This works as desired.

```
Expense = CALCULATE(SUM('GL Data'[Amount]),FILTER('GL Data','GL Data'[SubGrp1] = "EXPENSE"))
```

I want to sum the expense amount for the same time period of prior year.  My measure calculates correct data as of 11 months ago, not 1 year ago.  It appears to function as if the data calculation is looking at my system date, not the specified date:

```
Expense PY = CALCULATE([Expense], DATEADD(Dates[Date],-1,YEAR))
```

I've attempted using -12, -13 and MONTH in the DATEADD but the result doesn't correctly total 1 year ago.  I've also tried SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR() which provides wrong info.  Perhaps my Expense measure is the culprit.

My Date table is generated with this Dax:

[image]

Comment: Hello, It seems that problem is your date table.  How you defined start and end points of your date table ? Full dax code of date table would be great.

Comment: Hadn't considered the date table.  I attached a screenshot in the original post.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for the DAX code of date table. You can check my recommended solution below. I hope It solves your problem.

Comment: How do you source dates for [Expense] measure? What is a column name that you use for a context (slicer/filter/graph/row) ?.

Comment: The date is sourced from the Year slicer in my Date table

Answer (score 0):

Could you please use this as your date table, and test it. In your date table, you imposed no restrictions on the calendar auto() functions which I think is not useful. Also You used Generate function which ignores rows with blank values. In such a case, use GENERATEALL() function; but You need to form your date table like this:

```
Date =
VAR MinYear =
    YEAR ( MIN ( Fact_Table[Date_Column] ) )
VAR MaxYear =
    YEAR ( MAX ( Fact_Table[Date_Column] ) )
RETURN
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        FILTER (
            CALENDARAUTO ( 12 ),
            AND ( YEAR ( [Date] ) >= MinYear, YEAR ( [Date] ) <= MaxYear )
        ),
        "Calendar Year", "CY " & YEAR ( [Date] ),
        "Day", FORMAT ( [Date], "dddd" ),
        "Month Number", MONTH ( [Date] ),
        "Month", FORMAT ( [Date], "mmmm" ),
        "Year Month", FORMAT ( [Date], "mmm yy" ),
        "Year", FORMAT ( [Date], "YYYY" )
    )
```

After creating your Date Table, please do not forget to mark it as date table which is a good DAX practice as in the photo below.

[image: Click here to see image]

Comment: This seems to make no difference when implemented.